# How to call class method with self in python, which I need to transfer values?

Tags: python, class, methods, call, self

I'm doing leetcode 70 in python in my IDE. However it came up with error.

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        cache = [None] * (n + 1)
        return self._helper(n, cache)

    def _helper(self, n, cache):
        if n < 0:
            return 0
        if n == 1 or n == 0:
            return 1
        if cache[n]:
            return cache[n]
        cache[n] = self._helper(n - 1, cache) + self._helper(n - 2, cache)
        return cache[n]

step = Solution.climbStairs(13)

print(step)
```

The error is :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viktor/PycharmProjects/70. Climbing Stairs/70. Climbing Stairs.py", line 42, in 
    step = Solution.climbStairs(13)
TypeError: climbStairs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

How can I deal with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `Solution` and call the method on that.

```
s = Solution()
step = s.climbStairs(13)
```

Otherwise there's no `self` object.